# Can I restore a Windows 7 Disk Image to a second hard drive on a new computer?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I am going to have to replace my computer as it has reached the end of its working life.  It operates under Windows 7.  The new computers I am looking at already have Windows 7 installed and have two hard drives.  I have been using my existing computer for a number of years and really don't want to go to the bother of reinstalling all the applications and then configuring them as to how I like them.

I have seen software on sale that allows system transfers between computers with different configurations but am a bit dubious about using them.  What I would like to know is whether I can restore my system image produced using the Windows 7 utility on to the second hard drive of the new machine.  Would I then be able to use my old programs in the way I like without affecting the new Windows 7 configuration.

All my data files are backed up separately and there should be no problem restoring them.

Comment: You might need to clarify that - you mean to copy the drive to a **second** drive in your new machine, separate from the boot drive, & still have everything work as intended. Then no. You will in effect have 2 boot drives, each with programs, yet no way to differentiate which you boot from. your choices are, overwite the boot drive of the new machine [which is only likely to be partially successful, as drivers won't match, neither will the new machine be recognised as 'genuine' any more. The cleanest way to get round all bar the 'genuine' is to use Acronis Universal Restore, imho.

Answer (score 1):

**BACKUP**

Go to Control Panel, Backup your Files, Create a system image.
(http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/4241/how-to-create-a-system-image-in-windows-7/)

Put this System image on the new HDD and remove the original one.
.

**RECOVER**

Boot to your Win 7 CD.

Load System Image Recovery.

Follow the prompts (and select the file).
(http://www.goodells.net/dellrestore/win7/win7recovery.shtml)

Comment: Surprisingly, this method is actually pretty robust. Don't worry about additional software.